# Is there an elegant solution to $ \int_{0}^{b}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\frac{dx}{x+a} $?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this integral and I sense it could somehow be simplified using per partes, but so far I had no luck.

$$
\int_{0}^{b}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\frac{dx}{x+a}
$$

The neat thing is the boundary condition. Here, $a$ and $b$ are a real constants and $x>0$. We know that $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)|_{0}=0$. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not use $x$ both as a variable of integration and as an integration limit.

Comment: could you define what y is?

Comment: @mrtechtroid y is definitely a function here, if not then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ will just be $0$ and everything will go to $0$ too.

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$. Specifically, it is electric potential.